# Definite integral of $\cos(x^{2})$

Tags: integration

Looking at a double integral problem, and the inside integral is $\int_{y^{2}}^{4} y \cos(x^{2})\, dx$. I know there's an expression for the indefinite integral of $\cos(x^{2})$, but what do I do with a definite integral? Or is it just the same?

Comment: The obvious answer is change the order of integration.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that explains it!

Comment: What was the whole integral?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that you're looking at:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space\alpha}\left(\beta,\eta\right):=\int_\alpha^\beta\int_{\text{y}^2}^\eta\text{y}\cdot\cos\left(x^2\right)\space\text{d}x\space\text{d}\text{y}=\int_\alpha^\beta\text{y}\cdot\left\{\int_{\text{y}^2}^\eta\cos\left(x^2\right)\space\text{d}x\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}\tag1$$

Using:

$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot x^{4\text{n}}=\cos\left(x^2\right)\tag2$$

We can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space\alpha}\left(\beta,\eta\right)=\int_\alpha^\beta\text{y}\cdot\left\{\int_{\text{y}^2}^\eta\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot x^{4\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\int_\alpha^\beta\text{y}\cdot\left\{\int_{\text{y}^2}^\eta x^{4\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\int_\alpha^\beta\text{y}\cdot\left\{\frac{\eta^{1+4\text{n}}}{1+4\text{n}}-\frac{\text{y}^{2\left(1+4\text{n}\right)}}{1+4\text{n}}\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\left\{\frac{\eta^{1+4\text{n}}}{1+4\text{n}}\cdot\int_\alpha^\beta\text{y}\space\text{d}\text{y}-\frac{1}{1+4\text{n}}\cdot\int_\alpha^\beta\text{y}^{1+2\left(1+4\text{n}\right)}\space\text{d}\text{y}\right\}=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot\left\{\frac{\eta^{1+4\text{n}}}{1+4\text{n}}\cdot\frac{\beta^2-\alpha^2}{2}-\frac{1}{1+4\text{n}}\cdot\left(\frac{\beta^{2+8\text{n}}}{2+8\text{n}}-\frac{\alpha^{2+8\text{n}}}{2+8\text{n}}\right)\right\}\tag3$$